# Unrecognized selector sent to instance error with In app purchase product

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have a `UITableView` that users can select a custom sound from. I have 3 Non-consumables for IAP that I have logic built in for based on the `index.section` the user is selecting from. A `UIToolbarButton` changes in the logic (there's a separate `IBAction` where the user can save the selection, but only if they have "purchased" the product):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Pull identifiers for IAP
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    bool alarmpackpurchased = [defaults boolForKey:@"Alarm_Pack"];
    bool annoyancepackpurchased = [defaults boolForKey:@"Annoyance_Pack"];
    bool serenepackpurchased = [defaults boolForKey:@"Serene_Pack"];

    // Defualt index will always be allowed to save
    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        savebuybutton.enabled = YES;
        savebuybutton.title = @"Save";
        savebuybutton.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    else {

        if (indexPath.section == 1 && alarmpackpurchased == TRUE) {
            savebuybutton.enabled = YES;
            savebuybutton.title = @"Save";
            savebuybutton.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 2 && annoyancepackpurchased == TRUE) {
            savebuybutton.enabled = YES;
            savebuybutton.title = @"Save";
            savebuybutton.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 3 && serenepackpurchased == TRUE) {
            savebuybutton.enabled = YES;
            savebuybutton.title = @"Save";
            savebuybutton.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }

        else {
            savebuybutton.enabled = YES;
            savebuybutton.title = @"Buy Pack";
            savebuybutton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the `viewWillAppear:` method with the notification observer:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchased:) name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
}
```

Here's the error I receive after completing the IAP for this product:

```
2013-04-19 10:08:12.086 SleepLabBeta[43395:c07] -[AlarmSelectViewController productPurchased:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11444940
2013-04-19 10:08:12.125 SleepLabBeta[43395:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AlarmSelectViewController productPurchased:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11444940'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1bf5012 0x1666e7e 0x1c804bd 0x1be4bbc 0x1be494e 0x11274f9 0x1c4f0c5 0x1ba9efa 0x105bbb2 0x1f57a 0x1f0b3 0x1eeae 0x924b1 0x1b978fd 0x92437 0x930fa 0x93d27 0x922a4 0x227653f 0x2288014 0x22787d5 0x1b9baf5 0x1b9af44 0x1b9ae1b 0x1a3e7e3 0x1a3e668 0x5aaffc 0x297d 0x28a5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you didn't implement `productPurchased` method in `AlarmSelectViewController`.

**Note:** You may implement somewhere. Find and correct it.

Comment: I have this method imported from another class: `- (BOOL)productPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier {
    return [_purchasedProductIdentifiers containsObject:productIdentifier];
}`

Comment: But you set `addObserver:` as `self`. ? Then how get it will call? If that class is super class of `AlarmSelectViewController` means, it will get fire. Check with your code..

Comment: Are you saying that the observer would not be retrieved with and `#import ClassThatContainsproductPurchaseMethod.h`?

Comment: Sure. It won't fire.. Check with your code.. Implement same situation in another piece of code and check this logic...

Comment: THANK YOU! added this: `- (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification {
    
    NSString * productIdentifier = notification.object;
    [_products enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKProduct * product, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:productIdentifier]) {
           // do something here
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];
    
}`

Answer (score 2):

You might have not implemented `productPurchased` or using wrong parameters in the `productPurchased`. Also make sure that the viewController registering for the notification has this method implemented. If method is defined inside the other class then change the line to fit your className instead of self.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:yourClassObject selector:@selector(productPurchased:) name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
```

Add observer inside the `viewDidLoad` method instead of `viewWillAppear`

Comment: I have this method imported from another class: `- (BOOL)productPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier {
    return [_purchasedProductIdentifiers containsObject:productIdentifier];
}`

Comment: method should be inside the class where you are adding the observer.

Comment: I just tried to add the observer in `viewDidLoad` with the same results. productPurchased is in IAPHelper.m, and I have it set to import on this view controller. Is this a problem with setting `:self` in the observer?

Comment: Yes you should put `yourClassName` instead of `self` in case method is defined inside  `yourClass`

Comment: THANK YOU (just FYI, you and the other guy had the same answer but he beat you out by two minutes, no hard feelings? Here's the method I added: `- (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification {
    
    NSString * productIdentifier = notification.object;
    [_products enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKProduct * product, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:productIdentifier]) {
           // do something here
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];
    
}`